# Solve the following equation $\frac{\partial ^2u}{\partial x^2}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}.\quad 0<x<1, 0<t,$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

Solve the following equation $$\frac{\partial ^2u}{\partial x^2}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}.\quad 0<x<1, 0<t,$$ with

$$u(0,t)=-1\\ -\frac{\partial u(1,t)}{ \partial x}=(u(1,t)-1) \\ u(x,0)=x-1.$$
[image]
by using variable and separable method Let $ u(x,t)=X(x)T(t) \implies u_{xx}(x,t)=X''(x)T(t), u_t(x,t)=X(x)T(t)$

then given equation be $\frac{X''(x)}{X(x)}=\frac{T'(t)}{T(t)}=k \implies X''(x)-kX(x)=0, T'(t)-kT(t)=0$

This implies $X(x)=c_1e^{\sqrt{k}x}+c_2e^{-\sqrt{k}x}, T(t)=c_3e^{kt}$

I don't know how to use these boundary and initial conditions,,Any help?

Comment: Can you write down the solutions to $X''(x)-kX(x)=0$ and $T'(t)-kT(t)=0$?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy.. I did sir

Comment: Check your answer for $X(x)$ again.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy..soryy i rewritten

Comment: Something wrong with the question. There is no solution of the type $u(x,t)=X(x)T(t)$ because the condition $u(x,0)=x-1$ for all $x \in (0,1)$ cannot hold.

Comment: I think you need another initial condition of the type $u (a, x) = g (x)$ (where a is a real number) to be able to solve the equation

Comment: @AlexR.: Not a very good advice, if you don't have homogeneous boundary conditions (see my answer below).

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: That's not really the issue here. When using separation of variables, the initial condition is taken care of by forming a *linear combination* of separated solutions (each of which satisfies only the *boundary* conditions, which however need to be *homogeneous*).

Answer (score 1):

To apply the method of separation of variables, you need to have **homogeneous** boundary conditions, otherwise you can't linearly combine the separated solutions $u_n(x,t) = X_n(x) T_n(t)$ to obtain the sought solution $u(x,t) = \sum_n c_ n u_n(x,t)$ that also matches the initial condition.

Start by finding the equilibrium solution (the time-independent heat distribution that you expect $u$ to tend to as $t \to \infty$). If we call it $U(x)$, it's determined by $U_{xx}(x)=0$ for $0<x<1$, with boundary conditions $U(0)=-1$ and $-U_x(1)=U(1)-1$. Once you've calculated $U$, let $v(x,t) = u(x,t)-U(x)$, i.e., consider the *difference* between the temperature and the equilibrium that it tends to. Write down the corresponding initial-boundary value problem for $v$; it should have homogeneous boundary conditions. *Then* you can start thinking about separation of variables (if needed; in this case, the problem for $v$ turns out to be so easy that that's not even necessary).